# Why do I always get an error when trying to edit an answer?

Tags: bug, status-completed, edits, error-message

In past I didn't have this problem, but now if I try to edit an answer, I always get an error:

[image]

After this I usually reload the page, if I see that the message has been actually edited (so I got the error message box for no reason) I don't do anything, otherwise I try to edit it again. Why do I always get this error?

Comment: Or a question... just refresh the page and it goes away; my edits have always been "saved". Of course, it'd be great if it stopped...

Comment: does it happen every time you edit, or only some of the time?

Comment: It happens almost every time at the moment. There have been other problems today as well, my guess is that the SE sysadmin team is working on it already.

Comment: Also see https://twitter.com/stackstatus/status/290649005556391937 (20 hours ago).

Comment: Seems to happen to me every time, too.

Comment: Now seeing this while editing a *question* of mine.  The edits are actually going through, just the error is showing up.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Has now been deployed, if you see further errors **let me know**.

Recently I redid an awful lot of the edit pipeline, and there was a bug dealing with quick edits (no revisions) in the ajax editor.  Kind of a pain to reproduce locally honestly, but pretty common on the site itself.

The underlying bug was that we were responding with redirects to some ajax calls, which went to html, which our JavaScript couldn't parse, which was then reported as a generic error.  All the edits went through successfully though.

Comment: Was this also responsible for the convert to edit bug?

Comment: @casperOne different bug, same pipeline.

Comment: Is it fixed then i.e. are all bugs that extend from the pipeline fixed because the pipeline is fixed?

Comment: @casperOne The convert to edit bug was fixed yes, the pipeline has no known bugs at the moment.  This may not be the same as no bugs though...