# Error when editing answer

Tags: discussion, edits, error-message

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why do I always get an error when trying to edit an answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/163750/why-do-i-always-get-an-error-when-trying-to-edit-an-answer)

When editing any of my answers, I get...

`An error occurred saving the edit
(click on this box to dismiss)`

The edit seems to be saved irrespective of the error.

This has only started happening in the last hour or so - Is this a bug or is there some issue I'm unaware of?

Comment: This has happened to me too, but for questions.